# Calculate the average time duration between buying/selling of each share

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, pyspark

We have a table shares. It contains buy and sell orders of particular shares. All shares which are bought will be sold on same day and vice-versa. There can be cases when shares bought individually can be sold together and vice -versa.
For example, on `2023-03-31` GOOGLE shares of quantity 1 were sold at `10:03:34` and `10:03:42` and quantity of 2 shares bought together at `11:18:11`. The reverse situation is also possible when shares bought together in bulk and sold in distribution.

The time_in_seconds derived from time column by converting the hh:mm:ss to seconds.

It is guaranteed that records are sorted in order_execution_time.

We need to calculate the average time duration between buying / selling of each share.
For example, on `2023-03-31` GOOGLE 1 share sold at `10:03:34` bought back at `11:18:11`
another share of GOOGLE sold at `10:03:42` bought back at `11:18:11` (Note: 2 shares bought together)

Total Time Difference: (40691 - 36214) + (40691 - 36222) = 8946

Total trades: 2

Average Time Duration: 8946 / 2 = 4473 seconds

```
CREATE TABLE shares (
  symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
  trade_type TEXT NOT NULL,
  quantity integer,
  price integer,
  order_execution_time TEXT,
  time TEXT,
  time_in_seconds integer
);
```

```
INSERT INTO shares VALUES ('APPLE','sell',1, 539.2, '2023-02-17T09:38:59', '09:38:59', 34739); -- first order of selling share of APPLE. One trade active now.
INSERT INTO shares VALUES ('APPLE','buy',1, 536.7, '2023-02-17T10:40:05','10:40:05', 38405); -- sold share previously for APPLE bought back, No shares left to trade.
INSERT INTO shares VALUES ('GOOGLE','buy',1, 862.5, '2023-02-17T10:59:45','10:59:45', 39585); -- GOOGLE 1 share bought
INSERT INTO shares VALUES ('GOOGLE','sell',1, 861.05, '2023-02-17T12:55:22','12:55:22', 46522); -- GOOGLE 1 share sold. No shares left to trade.
INSERT INTO shares VALUES ('GOOGLE','sell',1, 876.05, '2023-03-31T10:03:34','10:03:34', 36214); -- GOOGLE 1 share sold
INSERT INTO shares VALUES ('GOOGLE','sell',1, 876.25, '2023-03-31T10:03:42','10:03:42', 36222); -- GOOGLE 1 shares sold (Now total 2 shares sold GOOGLE)
INSERT INTO shares VALUES ('GOOGLE','buy',2, 876.15, '2023-03-31T11:18:11','11:18:11', 40691); -- GOOGLE 2 shares bought together at same time. No shares left to trade.
```

Comment: Hi - what are the rules for selecting the records to compare? Given the infinite combinations of sequences of buy and sell records possible in a day, how would we know which records to compare when calculating time differences?

Comment: Why do you store time and timestamps as text? Using the data types time and timestamp/timestamptz would make more sense to me. Makes it a lot easier to do calculations

Comment: Make `order_execution_time` a `timestamptz` field and get rid of the `time` and `time_in_seconds` fields as they are redundant.

Comment: @NickW The rules when selecting records to compare are: Think of it as Intraday Trading. Positions are not carried forward next day.
1) Any share bought today will be sold today 
2) Any share sold today will be bought today
3) If 3 shares are bought earlier at time x together and sold individually at 3 different intervals (y1, y2, y3) then average time will be ( (y1-x) + (y2-x) + (y3-x) ) / 3
4) If 3 shares are sold earlier at different time x1, x2, x3 and bought together in single trade at time y then average time will be ( (y-x1) + (y-x2) + (y-x3) ) / 3

I hope this helps.

Comment: @FrankHeikens You can take time and timestamp as timestamp. Feel free to make changes if required. These columns are derived only for explanation purpose. In real data only order_execution_time column exist for time tracking.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The time_in_seconds and time column is derived only for explanation purpose. In real data such columns does not exist. Feel free to add or remove columns if required.

Comment: If you buy 3 shares at different times during the day and then sell them at three different times (or 2 shares in one sale and one share in another sale) - how do you match up a share bought with a share sold to then be able to calculate the duration?

Comment: @NickW It is FIFO (First In First Out)
Suppose If we buy 3 shares of GOOGLE at different times x1, x2, x3  
Situation 1: Sell them at 3 different time y1, y2, y3
Average time duration = ( (y1-x1) + (y2-x2) + (y3-x3) ) / 3

Situation 2: Sell 2 shares in one sale at y1 time and one share in another sale at y2 time Average time duration = ( (y1-x1) + (y1-x2) + (y2-x3) ) / 3

Comment: Someone else may be able to come up with a pure SQL solution to this but I think you’d need to write code/stored procedure to implement this type of logic

Comment: @NickW, I've posted pure SQL solutions to handle balanced and unbalanced daily trades. Whether trades are paired FIFO or randomly has no effect on balanced trades; however, the pairing method is important when unpaired trades are to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This table definition addresses some design issues present in the original post:

```
CREATE TABLE shares(
  symbol text NOT NULL,
  trade_type text NOT NULL,
  quantity integer NOT NULL,
  price integer NOT NULL,
  order_execution_time timestamptz NOT NULL
);
```

The following inserts the same information as in the original post:

```
INSERT INTO shares(symbol, trade_type, quantity, price, order_execution_time)
  VALUES ('APPLE', 'sell', 1, 539.2, '2023-02-17T09:38:59'),
         ('APPLE', 'buy', 1, 536.7, '2023-02-17T10:40:05'),
         ('GOOGLE', 'buy', 1, 862.5, '2023-02-17T10:59:45'),
         ('GOOGLE', 'sell', 1, 861.05, '2023-02-17T12:55:22'),
         ('GOOGLE', 'sell', 1, 876.05, '2023-03-31T10:03:34'),
         ('GOOGLE', 'sell', 1, 876.25, '2023-03-31T10:03:42'),
         ('GOOGLE', 'buy', 2, 876.15, '2023-03-31T11:18:11');
```

This query returns the mean time in seconds between complementary trades for each trade date:

```
SELECT symbol,
       DATE_TRUNC('day', order_execution_time) AS trade_date,
       ABS(  SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM order_execution_time) * quantity)
                FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'buy')
           - SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM order_execution_time) * quantity)
                FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'sell')) / (SUM(quantity) / 2) AS mean_time_seconds,
       SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'buy') = SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'sell') IS TRUE AS is_balanced
  FROM shares
 GROUP BY symbol,
          trade_date
 ORDER BY symbol,
          trade_date;
```

This query depends on each day having balanced buy and sell quantities. A check column, `is_balanced`, is `TRUE` for each day this requirement has been satisfied.

When run with the sample data, the query produces:

| symbol | trade_date | mean_time_seconds | is_balanced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | 2023-02-17 00:00:00 | 3666.0000000000000000 | `TRUE` |
| GOOGLE | 2023-02-17 00:00:00 | 6937.0000000000000000 | `TRUE` |
| GOOGLE | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 | 4473.0000000000000000 | `TRUE` |

The following query handles unbalanced daily trades by ignoring unmatched quantities:

```
WITH daily_trades AS (
SELECT symbol,
       DATE_TRUNC('day', order_execution_time) AS trade_date,
       order_execution_time,
       trade_type,
       quantity
  FROM shares),
daily_quantities AS (
SELECT symbol,
       trade_type,
       trade_date,
       order_execution_time,
       quantity,
       COALESCE(LEAST(SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'buy')
                                    OVER (PARTITION BY symbol, trade_date),
                      SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'sell')
                                    OVER (PARTITION BY symbol, trade_date)), 0) AS daily_quantity_limit,
       COALESCE(SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'buy')
                              OVER (PARTITION BY symbol, trade_date
                                    ORDER BY order_execution_time
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS purchased_quantity,
       COALESCE(SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'sell')
                              OVER (PARTITION BY symbol, trade_date
                                    ORDER BY order_execution_time
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS sold_quantity
  FROM daily_trades)
SELECT symbol,
       trade_date,
       ABS(  SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM order_execution_time) * LEAST(quantity, daily_quantity_limit - purchased_quantity))
                FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'buy')
           - SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM order_execution_time) * LEAST(quantity, daily_quantity_limit - sold_quantity))
                FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'sell'))
       / MIN(daily_quantity_limit) AS mean_time_seconds,
       SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'buy') = SUM(quantity) FILTER (WHERE trade_type = 'sell') IS TRUE AS is_balanced
  FROM daily_quantities
 GROUP BY symbol,
          trade_date
 ORDER BY symbol,
          trade_date;
```